# Fetch Source[ByteString, Any] out of stream into 2 sinks

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am trying to put incoming `Source[ByteString, Any]` into 2 `sinks` & trying to duplicate the incoming stream in `akka streaming graphs`. I am getting desired `'is'` as input stream but `bs` in not of type `Source[ByteString, Any]`. I am getting `boxed error`.

```
private def duplicateStream(content: Source[ByteString, Any]): Future[Either[X, Y]] = {
val sink = StreamConverters.asInputStream()
    val (is, bs): (InputStream, Future[ByteString]) = content
      .alsoToMat(sink)(Keep.right)
      .toMat(Sink.last)(Keep.both)
      .run()

//is is input stream which is desired
//bs should be Source[ByteString, Any]
}
```

How can I get `bs` as`Source[ByteString, Any]` out of this graph?

Comment: What should `bs` be compared to `content`? Same source? Should `content` be consumed once and fed back to a new source? What's the context and usage of this?

Comment: yes same source. content will be consumed to create 2 sinks & wanted to create same source out of the sink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using `[Broadcast]` in `akka streams`. It can be used to create multiple streams and use them independently.

```
val source: Source[Int, NotUsed] =
  Source.fromIterator(() => Iterator.continually(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100))).take(100)

val countSink: Sink[Int, Future[Int]] = Sink.fold(0)((acc, elem) => acc + 1)
val minSink: Sink[Int, Future[Int]] = Sink.fold(0)((acc, elem) => math.min(acc, elem))
val maxSink: Sink[Int, Future[Int]] = Sink.fold(0)((acc, elem) => math.max(acc, elem))

val (count: Future[Int], min: Future[Int], max: Future[Int]) =
  RunnableGraph
    .fromGraph(GraphDSL.createGraph(countSink, minSink, maxSink)(Tuple3.apply) {
      implicit builder => (countS, minS, maxS) =>
        import GraphDSL.Implicits._
        val broadcast = builder.add(Broadcast[Int](3))
        source ~> broadcast
        broadcast.out(0) ~> countS
        broadcast.out(1) ~> minS
        broadcast.out(2) ~> maxS
        ClosedShape
    })
    .run()
```

REF: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Broadcast.html#broadcast

Answer (score 0):

You're using `Sink.last` which will by definition keep only the last item of the source and materialize as a `Future` of that item.

Thus what you observe, you have the materialized values of both of your sinks: the inputstream and the last value.